Is "Ἐλλάχ" the proper Greek transliteration of "Allah"?
I would like your help in refuting a claim made by a Christian that has been bugging me for a while now.
A post in a forum claims that "Ἐλλάχ" is the "correct spelling in Greek" of "Allah."
Is the epsilon (ε) truly more fitting as a Greek transliteration of the first letter of the word "Allah" (as pronounced in Arabic)? Wouldn't starting with epsilon render the pronunciation of the rest of the word incorrect as in Arabic the second alpha isn't really 'a' but more of an 'o'? Besides, the l's are pronounced differently and the chi at the end would become silent.
I would be grateful if you could respond to this as both Christians and Muslims use this word to refer to God.

It's just such a ridiculous, obviously religiously-motivated argument. Do you really think that person will believe what some random SE site will say?

And for someone who keeps harping on 6's being "devilish", they sure missed the fact that 24 (which they say is the number of books in the Hebrew bible) is "6 + 6 + 6 + 6".

A much easier point of refutation is that long consonants in Hebrew aren't written by doubling the letter, no?

@Draconis Not that this nonsense is worth addressing, but FWIW, אללה is the standard Hebrew transcription of Allah.

@TKR Oh, interesting! Do you know why that is? I know in Arabic it's written with two lams because of the morpheme boundary, but that doesn't exist in Hebrew.

Why is this question on Latin.SE? It's about a Greek word for an Arabian deity, and the answer mentions Hebrew, but nowhere do I see anything very closely related to Latin.

Christian Arab speakers of the Byzantine empire used "Allāh al-ʼab", "al-ibn"  and "al-rūḥ al-quds" for  the Father, Son, and Holy spirit of their religion.

@Conrado It's not reflected in the SE name, but the site policy allows questions about ancient Greek.

@brianpck Ah, I see. Thanks!

Allah is الله ʔallāh, and it does start with an alif. It's also true that Modern Greek renders it as Αλλάχ. That's just about all the OP got right.
First of all, the comparison with Hebrew אֱלֹהַּ ʾĕlōah (actually an analogical creation based on the irregular plural אֱלֹהִים ʾĕlōhîm of אֵל ʾēl) is nonsensical: yes, it starts with an aleph, just as Allah starts with alif, but what the OP doesn't seem to realise is that aleph and alif are consonants—glottal stops in both languages—and what is being rendered in Greek is actually the following vowel. The glottal stop was never phonemic in Greek at any stage and at the start of a word wouldn't even have registered as a distinct sound to a Greek speaker (as indeed it clearly didn't to the OP), so it isn't reflected in writing.
(As an aside, Mark 15:34 actually has ἐλωῒ ἐλωῒ (λεμὰ σαβαχθάνι), not ἐλοΐ ἐλοΐ, and Matthew 27:46 has ἠλὶ ἠλὶ (λεμὰ σαβαχθάνι). Both are probably Aramaic (the rest of the quote certainly is), not Hebrew, but the Aramaic also starts with an aleph. Psalm 22 starts with the Hebrew equivalent: אֵלִי אֵלִי לָמָה עֲזַבְתָּנִי ʾēlî ʾēlî lāmā ʿăzaḇtānî.)
There is no reason to expect initial ε- in a Greek adaptation of Arabic ʔa- at any stage. In Classical Arabic a was generally realised as [a], just the same as Greek α at every stage of the language, and we would expect it to be rendered as such. We obviously don't have a ton of early Arabic loans into Greek, but Herodotus, in the 5th century BCE, actually already renders the name of Allat, a pre-Islamic Arabian goddess, as Ἀλιλάτ (presumably reflecting *ʔal-ʔilāt, which later became ʔallāt, just as ʔal-ʔilāh became ʔallāh).
The only place where Arabic ʔa- might seem to turn into ε- is in Modern Greek εμίρης 'emir', from Arabic أمير ʔamīr, but that's mediated by Ottoman Turkish emir; in Byzantine Greek (that is, the Greek of the Middle Ages), we actually have a direct loan from Arabic in ἀμηρᾶς /amiras/, also with α.
Engaging with the argument on its own level, there's also the point that some of our earliest manuscripts of the relevant passage of John (Papyrus 115, the earliest one, and the Codex Ephraimi Rescriptus, among others) actually give "the number of the beast" as 616, not 666. The Church father Irenaeus did affirm 666 as being the number of the beast in the 2nd century, but if we're taking Irenaeus as authoritative, we should also note that he strongly condemned exactly the sort of numerology the OP is engaging in as an absurdity in his Against Heresies. (He goes into some detail about how reducing Jesus to the number 888, as in the OP's username, is blasphemy, in particular.)
On a more sensible level, the point could be made that obviously John wouldn't have known about Allah either as a word or as a god, but taking a stance against prophecy being real is probably a non-starter in this sort of discussion, I guess.
None of it is worth devoting any attention to, to be honest. The OP is trying to rationalise his preëxisting Islamophobia by throwing things at the wall, not making a logical argument.

This was the best answer I've recieved in all this time , thank you

Also a slight question ,  this video claims that the alif is short and this is where the op gets the idea from that the word shud start with epsilon, does this have any basis?will replacing it with epsilon give it a more accurate transliteration looking at its pronunciation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0paH22-NvzU relevant part at 0 mins 40 seconds

Also what about the aramaic , elah which is essentially the root word for the Arabic , wouldn't that transliterate to greek with an epsilon even though it has an aleph

@Tahir That video is just wrong. He's pronouncing it as [æ], which is not the realisation in any current or historical dialect of Arabic that I'm aware of.

@Tahir A few Aramaic dialects have or had ĕ or ē as an initial vowel in the word that is cognate with the second part of Allah, and that would generally become ε (or η, as in Matthew, or conceivably ι or ει) in Greek, yes. Like I said, the aleph isn't relevant. It would also certainly only have one λ, and probably no rendering of the ה.

"but that's mediated by Ottoman Turkish emir": this seems to be a general shift.  In Turkish, the Takbir is called Tekbir and is pronounced "Allahu ekber": https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tekbir

@phoog can you tell me when this change came about? I see a lot of Turkish words with e pronounced as they have an a instead. And regardless I have heard from reputable linguists that they have attested transcriptions of the name Allah in greek being alpha , lambda ,lambda,alpha . Looks like they don't even include the chi at the end

@Tahir not really, I'm afraid I do not know.  I only know this by having encountered a handful of words in modern Bosnian that use E where Arabic uses A, and having confirmed that modern Turkish also uses E, so I guess I can say that it must have happened early enough for the change to have affected the Bosnian borrowings, so before or during the early Ottoman period in Bosnia, but I am confident that a proper linguist or even a literary scholar with knowledge of 15th century Turkish could give you a much better answer.

@Cairnarvon the professor that was cited for the greek , i think it was reverend Terence Espinoza , is he right about the way the epsilon is pronounced? Because I have come across a well established linguist in the Arabic field, marijn van putten, who said that the Arabic video that op cites (from arabic 101) is not reputable . He also mentioned that the word Allah is attested in greek transcription as alpha lambda lambda alpha . He didn't even mention the chi at the end, what do you think about this?

@Tahir Are we still on this? Greek ε was and is /e/, like English gate without the glide at the end, not /ε/ like get. I don't know what Terance Espinoza said because the video links are long gone, but it wouldn't surprise me if he's a clown—he's a theologian at a Bible school, not a linguist or classicist. Αλλάχ is the modern Greek spelling, like I said; it also wouldn't surprise me if Αλλα is attested historically. You can generally trust Marijn—I've taken some of his Leiden summer school classes and we run in adjacent circles, and I've never seen anything but good work from him.
